# What conditions to use to crystallise Equine Myoglobin?

Tags: crystal-structure, structural-biology

What are the crystallisation conditions for Equine Myoglobin?

I've tried repeating some from the PDB but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the 1958 Nature paper by [Kendrew](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/181662a0) include any useful details? (Sorry, I'm behind a paywall right now).